# Policy not correct when using sanctum in api

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to set up authorization using Laravel Policies so my policy is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use App\Models\Order;

class OrderPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function view(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        return $user->id === $order->user_id;
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
dd(auth('sanctum')->user()->can('view', $order)
```

it output `true` as expected, but when I use:

```
$this->authorize('view', $order);
```

it return `error 403` while I expect it to pass, I tried to debug using Xdebug and I set up a break point on the constructor of the OrderPolicy, what I noticed is that the passed user is null even if the correct sanctum barer token sent.

Here is screen shot of the debug panel:

[image]

How to solve this please?

Comment: is `sanctum` your default guard?

Comment: @lagbox No, but when I did make as default guard it worked correctly, is not there anyway else then making it default?

Comment: the authentication system needs to know what guard it is using at some point (otherwise it uses the default) ... if you intend on using the authenticated user this route should be behind the `auth` middleware which will set the guard as well ... `auth:sanctum`

Comment: @lagbox I have auth:sanctum middleware on this route, still not working with authorize() or can in middleware correctly

Comment: @lagbox is not somehow to make Laravel check all guards? or to set it in OrderPolicy itself?